# Refresh data from unrelated component React

Tags: reactjs, function, routes

I have a modal that is opened from an AppBar directly which let you insert data in the database.

On the current tab opened in background of modal, you can see a table with the current data, but the modal and the table aren't related. The page with the table is a route `/Dashboard` while the modal is just the modal, can be opened on front of any route.

I want that after you press the "Add" button in the modal to call the function that makes the `get` request on the `/Dashboard` route (which have the same named component).

I know about React Context but I that's all, I don't know exactly how to use it in this case after watching some tutorials.

This is my `/Dashboard` route:

```
const DashboardButton = (classes) => (
<Route render={({ history }) => (
    <Button
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={() => { history.push('/Dashboard') }}
    >
        Dashboard
    </Button>
)} />
```

)
which is in the same AppBar component as the modal.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add an App level context provider and have a variable there, possibly a boolean or a status that the data should update on `Dashboard` when you add data from `AppBar` modal. I made a quick demo, check it out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-dew-8rfho?file=/src/App.js